# Flutter app crashes on hot restart only on iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Not sure what is going on, but when I hot restart my flutter app crashes using iOS simulator. Hot restart works fine on an Android simulator. I even tried to uninstall and install XCode again.
Here is what gets printed on the terminal

```
[ +459 ms] Hot restart performed in 924ms.
[   +3 ms] Restarted application in 936ms.
[ +900 ms] Service protocol connection closed.
[        ] Lost connection to device.
[   +3 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device (file:///Users/frederickmfinanga/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/775342AF-E52F-46EB-9CDB-9C29720FC357/data/Containers/Data/Application/D093EF45-D895-481C-B965-CA56F7881A5C/tmp/the_hair_routinenSBAWo/the_hair_routine/)
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"46","method":"getMemoryUsage","params":{"isolateId":"isolates/4165970133496907"}}
[ +257 ms] Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after 0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 646,839ms.
[ +259 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 242ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0
```

Comment: Could it be because you don't have permissions to delete that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. After two days of debugging I have just found out it was caused by one of my dependencies. It is [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package version 1.1.3.

As I can see the issue is resolved in firebase_auth 1.1.4 released on 10th of May 2021.

So just update to firebase_auth 1.1.4 if you use this package

Comment: Yes, I ended up updating my firebase packages shortly after posting this aswell. But wasn't sure if that was the issue, hence didn't answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced something similar a few days back.

There can be two possibilities why it is happening :

- You have not granted permission for something you are trying to access (like getting the location/camera ). If this is the case then read the docs of the package you might be using and add the permissions programatically.
- Sometimes our podfile reference gets corrupted. (This is what happened in my case). For this delete your `podfile.lock` file (ios/podfile.lock). For a fresh start you can also delete your `pubspec.lock` as well. And then do a `flutter pub get` or simply run your app.